# Embed controllers in a template

Tags: php, fosuserbundle, symfony4

I have a controller named UserController, that contains 1 method that list all active users on the website:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function whoIsOnlineAction()
    {
        $users = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('App\\Entity\\User::class')->getActive();
        //return new Response(array('users' => $users));
        return $this->render('bundles\\FOSUserBundle\\layout.html.twig', ['users' => $users]);
        //return array('users' => $users);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to embed controller on layout.html.twig template. This template can be found on templates/bundles/FOSUserBundle folder, and contains:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for user in users %}
        {{ user.firstname }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

This template extends base.html.twig template, who can be found in templates folder and contains that:

```
<body>
        {% block content %}
        {{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\UserController:whoIsOnlineAction')) }}

        {% endblock content %}
</body>
```

When I run for a test, I got this error:
Variable "users" does not exist.

Comment: Is `whoIsOnline` being called through a route or just included in the layout ? Looks like you could remove the `extends` and `block content` and just leave the loop in there.

Comment: @msg Is just included in the layout. I removed the `extends` and `block content` but now nothing appears just a blank page and an exception ** Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted**

Comment: Increase your `memory_limit` in `php.ini`, but could you return just one user to confirm the template is working?

Comment: @msg done and I run with `php -d memory_limit bin/console server:run` but still the same error.

Comment: @msg No when I return a response on my controller like that `return new Response($users[0]);` or `return new Response($users[0]);`, I got a result. And then try to list all active user `{% for user in users %} {{ user.firstname }}{% endfor %}`, I got this exception **An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "array" given.").**